# How can split field results with multiple values in PHP?

Tags: split

I try to split a field with a multiple values, i have this field..

COLORS with this values separated by |..

blue|yellow|green|white

```
function getAutocomplete($term) {

    global $db;
    global $config_table_prefix;
    $result = $db->fetchRowList("SELECT `colors` from ".TABLE_COLORS." where `colors` like '$term%' limit 10");

//This code need some code here to split this values

    return $result;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume your working with PHP so use the function [explode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php), you'll get an array :

`$result = explode("|", $result);`

Comment: Yes you have i right! But it is not working with this my autocomplete is working but not this

Comment: Well if its already an array, you don't need to split it then, just so you know, the opposite of explode is implode

Comment: The output is the name Array only

Comment: Now with implode i dont take output

Comment: @GiannisStamoutsos try print_r($result);